# How do I include the resources from a qooxdoo library

Tags: qooxdoo

I have created a custom library with resources.  It is an editor component that uses the ace editor.  So I created the library/app and it works fine.  However, when I try to use it in another app by adding a "libraries" entry to the config.json file of the app, it doesn't include the ace files in the resources  folder from the custom library.  How do I get those files included?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add an `@asset` hint to your application class, pointing to an asset in the library.

So, for example, if your library's namespace is *mycustomlib*, you have to add `@asset(mycustomlib/*)` in your application class.